# Does the Sony VAIO VGN-AW11Z/B laptop (Intel PM45 chipset, 2 memory bays) support 16GB of RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory, sony-vaio

I do know that Intel suggests PM45 supports 8GB, but those are rather old specs when 8GB sticks were not available. I wonder if anyone has tried 2x 8GB sticks on the VAIO? or even 2x 16GB sticks for a total of 32GB...

Comment: what does crucial.com Say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this Intel page you can only use 8GB:

> **Memory Specifications** 
>   **Max Memory** Size (dependent on memory type)    **8 GB**

http://ark.intel.com/products/35135/Intel-82PM45-Memory-Controller-Hub

And if the memory controller doesn't support more RAM, you can't use it.

Comment: Thanks - I looked into Wikipedia as well and I think even trying more RAM is not a great idea :(